# Where is the system's "sys" user's password hash stored in Debian?

Tags: debian, users, password, shadow

I want to get the password hash of the `sys` user in Debian (but the password is preferred). I heard that all password hashes are stored in the `/etc/shadow` file, but there isn't a password hash for the `sys` user.

How to get it?

P.S. I have root access.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. The `sys` user on Debian is a system user that (AFAIK) exists at this point just for legacy reasons, and thus is not supposed to have a usable login (and if you _really_ need to run something as them, you can just use `sudo -u sys /bin/bash` to get a shell running as that user, but you should _never_ need to do that).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a usual desktop installation, what you see in `/etc/shadow` is what you get, and the system users generally don't have passwords set. They're not used for interactive logins, so they don't need passwords.

E.g. on the system I looked at, `/etc/shadow` has this line for `sys`:

```
sys:*:19101:0:99999:7:::
```

That `*` is where the password hash would be if the user had a password. But `*` is an invalid password hash, no password will produce it, so there is no password the user could log in with.

Note that if the password hash field was empty, it might allow login without entering a password. With the Linux PAM libraries, this is controlled by the `nullok` setting to `pam_unix.so` ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_unix.8.html)):

> `nullok`
> The default action of this module is to not permit the user access to a service if their official password is blank. The `nullok` argument overrides this default.

(if it's enabled, and the password is empty, the module doesn't even ask for the password but accepts the login directly.)

If you really wanted, you could set a password for the system in the usual way, but I would suggest reconsidering what you're doing; there's probably a better way. Also note that they may not have a usable shell set either, e.g. on the system I looked, the `sys` user's shell is set to `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

Comment: No, when I tried empty password, I got "Login Invalid"

Comment: @VadSim If the user does not have a hash in `/etc/shadow`, that means that the user does not have a password. _It does not mean that the password is the empty string_.

Comment: As @Kusalananda says: *No password* is not equal to the empty string as password. Having users with the empty string as password would be a massive security hole.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, in some systems, an empty password hash means login without giving a password is allowed.

Comment: @ilkkachu: How does that in any way relate to what I said? That just means you can make the security hole I talked about, you can also *not* lock the door when you leave home.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, I'm just saying that on some systems, an empty password hash acts the same as having the empty string as an accepted password. (Bar the difference between actually needing to enter that empty string vs. just getting in without being asked for it. If that matters, then yes, a password of the empty string would need to have a hash installed for it as usual.)

Comment: @Kusalananda, post it as an answer and I'll mark it as a solution

Comment: @VadSim My comment does not answer the question, and what I said is now already well encapsulated by ikkachu's answer.