# What's the difference between empty password and no password?

Tags: linux, debian, password, passwd

As said [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705032/where-is-the-systems-sys-users-password-hash-stored-in-debian) in comments, empty password and no password are different things. So what's the difference between empty password and no password in Linux Debian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One still has a password hash, but the other does not.

Password hashing functions can accept an empty string. So if the front end interface allows the user to submit an empty string as a password, then the password will validate. If this is the case, there is an actual password hash stored on the back end that will only validate if the password hashing function receives an empty string. Any other input will result in authentication failure.

If there is no password at all, there is no password hash, and the field where that hash is normally located is completely empty. No matter what attempted password is supplied, authentication will never succeed.

Comment: re. that last paragraph: as I mentioned in an answer to the linked question, if `pam_unix.so` is used with the `nullok` option, an empty password field is automatically accepted as a valid login. On the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system I last installed, it was enabled by default, and the [Debian changelog](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/p/pam/pam_1.4.0-9+deb11u1_changelog) for the PAM packages also seems to indicate it's set by default: "pam (1.4.0-1): debian/pam-configs/unix: use nullok, not nullok_secure."

Comment: The other way to have "no password" is to have a nonempty but invalid hash, like `*` or `!` (or `!` followed by a valid hash, which is what `usermod -L` might do). Those would never be accepted.

Comment: Totally agreed, and definitely useful background information! My answer was intended to keep things simple relative to the original question, but your additional detail provides better coverage.